# "уж" vs "и" as an intensifier

Tags: словоупотребление

> 1) Слишком **уж** много сил для них нужно.
>
> 2) Негоже нам **и** дальше прошлым жить.

I'm assuming "уж" and "и" both serve as an intensifying particle here, but I'm not sure when to use one or the other. As for the intensifier "же", I use it to draw some contrast to a previous statement, as in:

> Как **же** здесь красиво!

... but what is the difference between "уж" vs "и" as an intensifier?

Is it possible to paraphrase the two phrases with "уж" and "и" swapped around?

Comment: There is an old mnemonic about words ending on `ж`, written without `ь`: `уж замуж невтерпеж`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't swap intensifiers in 1) and 2).

"Уж" *in this kind of context* sort of strengthens the extent of strengthening, and "и" just strengthens the extent (of the adverb).

Trying to put together some rule of thumb here, use "уж" where you could/would double the adverb. Like, "нет уж!" as "no, no!" vs. "нет!" as "no!". Here, "too much effort" as "слишком много сил" vs. "too, too much effort" vs. "слишком уж много сил". And use "и" otherwise.